# Ruby On Rails nofollow to non internal link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nofollow

I have a text paragraph where it may have external or internal URL. User will enter this text. So, I want external links should add `rel=nofollow` and internl links won't be having `rel=nofollow` attribute.

**Internal links** can be:

```
 <a href=http://www.mysite.com"> My Site </a>
```

or
     `<a href="/articles/1-world-cup-cricket-2015"> World cup schedule </a>`

**External link** is as usual anything...

My current function is adding `rel=nofollow` to all internal and external links.

```
def add_nofollow html
  html.gsub(/\<a href=["'](.*?)["']\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/mi, '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow" target="_new" >\2</a>')
end
```

**The question** is how do I add the rel=nofollow to external links only?

Comment: Please, begging for people not to downvote your post is pathetic and just adds needless clutter. Don't keep doing this.

Comment: @CodyGray you are right. But I find some people don't read content but just title and downvote. sorry I will remove by above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails you can use regex to find urls and add rel=nofollow to them.

```
def add_nofollow html

 html.scan(/(\<a href=["'].*?["']\>.*?\<\/a\>)/).flatten.each do |link|
   if link.match(/\<a href=["'](http:\/\/|www){0,1}((localhost:3000|mysite.com)(\/.*?){0,1}|\/.*?)["']\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/)
    else
    link.match(/(\<a href=["'](.*?)["']\>(.*?)\<\/a\>)/)
    html.gsub!(link, "<a href='#{$2}' rel='nofollow' target='_new' >#{$3}</a>" )
    end
  end
  html
end
```

`

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

see [this link](http://regexr.com?35q8q) for my example. is use regex `<a href=["']((http://www.mysite.com)(/.*?){0,1}|/.*?)["']\>(.*?)\<\/a\>` to get all link match your internal link.

Comment: Thanks it help me a lot to complete follow method written by me.